# JProfiler does not show all calls

Tags: java, jprofiler

I'm trying to profile writing of a gif, but the self time does not add up. So I have no idea what's going on.

[image: JProfiler Call Tree]

edit: added method in question with formating

```java
private final ImageWriter gifWriter;

   void writeToSequence(RenderedImage img) throws IOException
   {
      gifWriter.writeToSequence(
            new IIOImage(
                  img,
                  null,
                  imageMetaData),
            imageWriteParam);
   }
```

edit 2: profiling with javax.imageio

[image: filter]

[image: with image io]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> self time does not add up

The call tree shows total times. Self time is the difference between the total time and the sum of all child nodes. You can switch on the additional self time display in the view settings.

In your case, most time is spent directly in the `GifSequenceWriter.writeToSequence` method.

An additional topic that is relevant in this case is that JProfiler has a concept of call tree filters. If a class is unprofiled and is still shown in the tree (because is it called directly by a profiled class or because it is at the top level of the tree), it can have a large self time due to calls to other unprofiled methods. This is not the case for your `GifSequenceWriter` class, but it is the case for the `GifImageWriter` class below it. You can recognize unprofiled classes by the red corner in the top left of the method icon.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I added the method in question above. based on your aswer i would guess that creating a IIOImage takes so long, but it dosent show up in the call tree. is there a way to profile IIOImage as well

Comment: i moved the creaton of IIOImages in a seperate method so JProfile can pick it up. it takes ~100ms and there are still ~18,000ms left for GifSequenceWriter.writeToSequence. i dont get it.

Comment: Can you add `javax.imageio.` as as inclusive filter in the call tree filters and profile again?

Comment: OK, it must be the "com.sun.imageio." package where the image writer is implemented. "com.sun." packages are filtered in a sepcial way in JProfiler. Try adding the "com.sun.imageio." as an inclusive filter as well.